# Trouble in making a while bucle in a blackjack game

Tags: java

```
private static void generarbanca() {
    int valorcartabanca;
    do {
        int valorcartabancamin = 1;// from one to 11
        valorcartabanca = valorcartabancamin + (byte) (Math.random() * 10);
    }while (valorcartabanca<15);
}
```

`valorcartamin` is the minimun number that I want to generate for the crupier, so the problem is that program get in a infite loop.
I want it to generate number until 15 point score is reached and count the number needed till 15 and so on.

Comment: I'm afraid while it's clear why there's an infinite loop, it's not clear what you want to do. You've said `valorcartabancamin` goes from 1 to 11, but it doesn't, it's always 1. Do you mean to increment it? Or to repeatedly add to `valorcartabanca`, or...?

Answer (score 1):

`1 + (Math.random() * 10)` will always be less than 15. Did you want to write

```
valorcartabanca += valorcartabancamin + (byte) (Math.random() * 10);
```

Note the `+=` instead of a simple `=`.

Comment: no, I want the program to generate values from 1-11 until it's 15 or more

Comment: @IagoPalleiro well, numbers from 1-11 will **never** be 15 or more.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the initialization of valorcartabancamin from the loop, and in addition you need to keep the current value of valorcartabanca, so use the += operator:

```
 private static void generarbanca() {
    int valorcartabancamin = 1;// desde uno hasta 11
    int valorcartabanca = 0;
    do {
        valorcartabanca += valorcartabancamin + (byte) (Math.random() * 10);
    } while (valorcartabanca<15);
}
```

Comment: You can't use `+=` when you haven't initialized `valorcartabanca`.

Answer (score -1):

you are not accumulating valorcartablanca.
try

```
int valorcartabanca = 1;
do {    
    valorcartabanca = valorcartabancamin + (byte) (Math.random() * 10);
}while (valorcartabanca<15);
```